# Bootstrap dropdown disappears too quickly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using a Bootstrap dropdown menu. 
It all worked fine untill i made some changes I can't undo anymore.
When I go to [my website](http://www.genietenaanzee-blankenberge-zeedijk.web44.net) on a mobile phone the dropdown disappaers after 1-2 seconds.
If I use the original bootstrap it works fine but when I use my own it doesn't.
I searched everywhere for the answer but I haven't found a solution.
I also made a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8yg8hnp/) to show you.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inverseNavbar1">
                  <span class="sr-only"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="inverseNavbar1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="info">Info<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="foto">Foto's<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="beschikbaarheid">Beschikbaarheid</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="prijzen">Prijzen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: after the the click on the dropdown the code adds a "collapsing" class to your wrapping div of your navbar-nav. After animation is played it toggles the "collapse" class agian. That's wrong the it should have any extra classes or a class like"open" or something similar. So the issue is somewhere in the code, but its too long for me to take further look at it now

Comment: This is not gonna answer this specific question. Just writing for people searching and ending up here. I had a similar problem of the dropdown disappearing right after click. Turns out it is because I was using a CustomMenu and I was not passing the ref to it. Look here for more detail: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#custom-dropdown-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that at least one rule is missing from the bootstrap.css.
If you add:

```
.collapse.in {        
      display: block;       
}
```

You get the functionallity back but the animation does not look good.

In bootstrap the navbar when collapsed will have classes

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse"></div>
```

During animation it will get:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapsing" aria-expanded="true" style="height:SOMEHEIGHT"></div>
```

And after, when visible

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collaps in" aria-expanded="true"></div>
```

Without the css rule, when the animation of the menu is finished the menu was not shown because there exist a rule that hides all items with class collapse:

```
.collapse {
  display: none
}
```